# PHP Unit: Create common object to work with

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm writing PHP Unit tests for a class, which make some curl requests. At the moment every test starts with my class instance initiation and login directive and ends with logout directive, e.g.

```
public function testSomeMethod(){
        $a = new myClass();
        $a->login();
        ....
        $a->logout();
        $this->assertTrue($smth);
```

I want to create one common object $a = new myClass(), call login method before all test and logout method after all tests. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In accordion with the PHPUnit documentation [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) you can use the following hook method:

> The setUp() and tearDown() template methods are run once for each test
>   method (and on fresh instances) of the test case class.

Also

> In addition, the setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass() template
>   methods are called before the first test of the test case class is run
>   and after the last test of the test case class is run, respectively.

In your case you can define the login class as class member and instantiate (login) in the `setUpBeforeClass()` method and do the logout in the `tearDownAfterClass()`

**EDIT: EXAMPLE**

Consider the following class:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;


class MyService {


    public function login()
    {
        echo 'login called'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        echo 'logout called'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function doService($name)
    {
        echo $name.PHP_EOL;
        return $name;
    }
}
```

This test case:

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\Service\MyService;

class MyServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \Acme\DemoBundle\Service\MyService
     */
    protected static $client;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$client = new MyService();
        self::$client->login();
    }

    public function testSomeMethod1()
    {
        $value = self::$client->doService("test1");
        $this->assertEquals("test1",$value);
    }

    public function testSomeMethod2()
    {
        $value = self::$client->doService("test2");
        $this->assertEquals("test2",$value);
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        self::$client->logout();
    }
}
```

> Dump the following output:
>
> login called .test1 .test2 logout called
>
> Time: 49 ms, Memory: 6.00Mb
>
> OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)

hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matteo

I spend hello lot of time creating a reusable object inside a class. this one worked `setUpBeforeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Creating reusable / common object at class level ( to be use in methods/functions) answer by @Matteo was helpful, Here is my implementation

no need for multiple inheritance , or __construct() constructor, I spent a lot of time on that ( specially coming from java background)

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Services\HelperService;

class HelperServiceTest extends TestCase
{ 
    //Object that will be reused in function()'s of this HelperServiceTest class itself 
    protected static $HelperServiceObj;

   //this is the magic function
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$HelperServiceObj = new HelperService();
    }

    public function testOneHelperServiceToBeTrue()
    {
          $this->assertTrue(self::$HelperServiceObj->getValue());
    }

   public function testTwoHelperServiceToBeTrue()
    {
          $this->assertTrue(self::$HelperServiceObj->getValueTwo());
    }

}
```

Refer official docs  [setUp() , setUpBeforeClass() , tearDown()](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html)  for magic function like  `setUpBeforeClass()`

Sample implementation of `getValue()` function in `HelperServiceTest` class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class HelperServiceTest
{
    function getValue(){
       return true;
    }

    function getValueTwo(){
       return true;
    }

}
```